# How to handle ForeingKey fields in DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models with ForeignKey relation

```
class Order(models.Model):

    ip =  models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class OrderItem(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sssize', default = None)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="item", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my serializer

```
class CreateOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        exclude = ('is_ordered',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
    
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.update_or_create(
            product = validated_data.get('product',None),
            quantity = validated_data.get('quantity', None),
            size = validated_data.get('size',None),
        )
        return order_item
```

I need to somehow get or create Order object base on ip (which i get from request) and is_ordered fields and pass it to serializer or do it in view
I have tried to add order field in view.py after i get my serialized data but i get an error saying that order field is required
View.py

```
    def post(self, request, pk):
        serializer = CreateOrderItemSerializer(  data=request.data, )
        print(serializer.initial_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product = serializer.save()

            ip = get_client_ip(request)
            
            order = Order.objects.get_or_create(ip = ip, is_ordered = False)
            product.order.add(order.id)
```

Or need i get ip strait from POST method JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `Order` either in the `view` or inside the `serializer`. In any case you can pass that information to the `serializer` via [`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

views.py

```py
class OrderItemAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ...
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ip = get_client_ip(request)
        serializer = CreateOrderItemSerializer(data=request.data, context={'ip': ip})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also, you need to "tell" your `serializer` that the order field is not required in the payload, you can do that with additional [`keyword arguments`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments):

serializers.py

```
class CreateOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        exclude = ("is_ordered",)
        extra_kwargs = {"order": {"required": False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ip = self.context.get("ip")
        ref_code = str(random.randint(0, 10000))
        order = Order.objects.create(ip=ip, ref_code=ref_code)

        validated_data.update({"order": order})

        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return order_item
```